# Developing Markov Transition Matrix

Tags: credit, mbs, markov, transition-matrix

I’m working with historical credit performance data and would like to build a transition matrix to predict defaults and delinquencies.  I can model the transition between states (ie current - delinquent) based on some covariates using a logit or other technique.  Can I assemble a transition matrix simply from the predicted state-to-state probabilities or is it more complicated?

Comment: And why aren’t standard methods sufficient? E.g. https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf

Comment: https://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2093&context=art_sci_etds  Describes building a conditional Markov chain with multinomial logistic regression to set the transition probabilities.  I’m thinking of doing the same thing, but modeling state transitions with machine learning techniques - im hoping to understand what can go wrong with this approach.  Thanks for the feedback!